# Apex 5.1 Custom LDAP not working in 2nd parsing schema

Tags: ldap, oracle-apex-5.1

I am on Apex 5.1 in a hosted environment and have an application that uses a custom LDAP authentication function.  It works fine when the application is running on the Production schema.   I now wanted to make some changes to the schema and application, so our hosting vendor added a 'DEV'  schema on same instance with exactly the same data and objects as PROD and I then exported the application and used the DEV schema as the parsing schema when I imported it back to same Workspace so I could make changes to the application without touching prod data.  This set up works fine when I use the Application Express authentication and go ahead and make changes to the DEV schema and to the application, but when I try to test my changes using the custom LDAP authentication, I am getting Invalid Session thrown by DBMS_LDAP.  Since both schemas are on the same oracle server, I assumed that the same LDAP function that works in PROD schema should work with the DEV schema.  Looking at the custom LDAP function, there is no  reference to schema owner so what am I missing? I would have assumed identical functions should function identically against the same Oracle server even though coming from 2 different schemas.  Does my hosting vendor need to make sure ACLs for both schemas (PROD and DEV) are identical??

Thanks,
Pat

Comment: I discovered from our hosting service that ACLs were not opened up to the DEV schema.  Once ACLs were adjusted, LDAP worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

My guess was correct.  ACLs were not set identical for both schemas.  Once ACLs were adjusted, LDAP worked as expected.